# mysql search query with user given multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing a search option using php. there i need to do search using user given criteria user can be search when user give id,name,status any of combination of these three parameters.below is my code

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        echo "<script> document.getElementById('tblsearch').style.display = 'block' </script> "; 

        $serviceNumber=$_POST['serviceNumber'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $pendingfrom=$_POST['pendingfrom'];
        $status=$_POST['status'];
        $datefrom=$_POST['datefrom'];
        $dateto=$_POST['dateto'];
        $searchkey='serviceNumber';




$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "user_management");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE ';
    $where = array();
    $values = array();
    $types = '';

    if (!empty($_POST['serviceNumber'])) {
        $where[] = 'serviceNumber = ?';
        $values[] = $_POST['serviceNumber'];
        $types .= 'i';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $where[] = 'Username = ?';
        $values[] = $_POST['name'];
        $types .= 's';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['status'])) {
        $where[] = 'status = ?';
        $values[] = $_POST['status'];
        $types .= 's';
    }



      $query .= implode(' AND ',$where);
      printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $query);



  printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $values);

/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* Bind variable for placeholder */

    $stmt->bind_param($types,$values);

    /* execute statement */

    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

    printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $stmt->num_rows);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

> below line i was going confused,because $values is an array.i need to pass user given paremeters to this in order to execute.

```
$stmt->bind_param($types,$values);
```

> so in order to get correct results how do i need to do this.

Comment: You can `foreach` the `$values` array and bind the appropriate parameter for each iteration of the loop.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using below:

```
     if(isset($_POST['search']))
      {
      echo "<script> document.getElementById('tblsearch').style.display = 'block' </script> "; 

    $serviceNumber=$_POST['serviceNumber'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $pendingfrom=$_POST['pendingfrom'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $datefrom=$_POST['datefrom'];
    $dateto=$_POST['dateto'];
    $searchkey='serviceNumber';




$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "user_management");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE ';

if (!empty($_POST['serviceNumber'])) {
   $query .="serviceNumber='$searchkey'  ";

}

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
          $query .="and Username='$name'  ";

}

if (!empty($_POST['status'])) {
    $where[] = 'status = ?';
    $values[] = $_POST['status'];
          $query .=" and status='$status' ";
}




/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

/* Bind variable for placeholder */

$stmt->bind_param($types,$values);

/* execute statement */

$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $stmt->num_rows);

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}

     /* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This opens you up to SQL Injection. Is a horrible way of doing things...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call a function with an array of parameters. The parameters need to be stored as references in order to be passed to the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method. Long story short, you need an array where the 1st value is a string and the rest are references to your parameters.

For example:

```
$bindParams = [$types];
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $bindParams[$key] = &$value;
}

call_user_func_array(
  [$stmt, 'bind_param'], //array with the object and the method - callable
  $bindParams
);
```

Comment: Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\User_managemet\search.php on line 331

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\User_managemet\search.php:335 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\User_managemet\search.php on line 335